# How to increase key by 1 in LinkedHashMap when calling method

Tags: java, increment, linkedhashmap

Please help me find a solution.
I need if the word is checked it was added to `LinkedHashMap` and for each added word the key was increased by 1.
I don't know how many words I will write, so I can't use a loop.

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer,String> terms= new LinkedHashMap();
LinkedHashMap<Integer,String> definitions=new LinkedHashMap();
public void menuItem() {

    int iTerms=0;
    int iDef=0;
    boolean point=true;
    while (point){
        System.out.println("Input the action (add, remove, import, export, ask, exit):");
        String item=scanner.nextLine();
        switch (item){
            case "add":
                Items.addCard(terms,definitions,iTerms,iDef);
                break;
            case "remove":
             //   Items.removeCard(terms,definitions*/);
                break;
            case "import":
                Items.importCard();
                break;
            case "export":
                break;
            case "ask":
                break;
            case "exit":
                point=false;
                break;
        }
    }
}

public static void  addCard(LinkedHashMap terms,LinkedHashMap definitions,int iTerms,int iDef){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String it,answer;
   

    System.out.println("The card:");
    it=scanner.nextLine();
    if(terms.containsValue(it)){
        System.out.println("The card \""+it+"\" already exists.");
    }else {
      // ++iTerms;
        terms.put(++iTerms, it);
        System.out.println(iTerms+"The definition of the card:");
        answer = scanner.nextLine();
        if(definitions.containsValue(answer)){
            System.out.println("The definition \""+answer+"\" already exists.");
        }else {
            iDef++;
            definitions.put(iDef,answer);
            System.out.println(iDef+"The pair (\""+ terms.get(iTerms)+"\":\""+definitions.get(iDef)+"\") has been added.");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(terms);
    System.out.println(definitions);
}
```

When executing this code, no matter how much I add the key will be 1 (and with each added should increase).

Comment: Are you sure you want to increase *key*? Keys in maps need to be unique. Usually we would map `word -> amount` and when counter for some *word* needs to be increased we simply put increased *value* for that word.

Comment: Is this an attempt to use maps as wrong as possible?

Comment: _no matter how much I add the key will be 1_ Obviously, because each time you call method `addCard` you create a new, empty `LinkedHashMap`. I suggest that you make `terms` a class member and initialize it in the constructor. Also, I think you mixed up this line of the code in your question: `terms.put(++iTerms, it);` I think that should be: `terms.put(it, ++iTerms);`

Comment: <Integer,String> ago (++iTerms, it) you are right when calling the class, I create a new object, I edited the code, but the result did not change

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `containsKey()` method ! Something like this

```
if(map.containsKey(1)){
    map.put(map.keySet().stream().findFirst().get()+1 , your_String_value); //Increment one to two and likewise
}
```

Comment: My bad, updated the code, you may do something similar to it ! not exactly the same but showed the way :)

Comment: map.get(1)+1  get return String value

Comment: Check if above code works for you !

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present